# How to make the nav visible while you reaching the bottom of the site?

Tags: javascript, scroll, visibility

I don't know why but the nav should appear again when I reach the bottom of the site. How can I fix that?

Opposite works = every time you reach the top of the site, the nav appears. If you scroll down at the beginning = nav disappears + if you hover on the nav = it appears again and disappears by leaving it.

nav appears while at the top + disappears while scrolling

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
$('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ? "0" : "1")
  })
})
```

nav show and hide while hovering

```
$('nav').mouseover(function() {
  $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", "1");
});

$('nav').mouseout(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", "0");
  }
});
```

nav should appear while reaching the bottom / doesn't work?!

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
  $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", "1");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have added condition to detect top and bottom and shown navbar accordingly

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navbar = $('.nav-visibility')
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    //Check for top and bottom
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() || $(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        navbar.css("opacity", "1");
    }else{
      navbar.css("opacity", "0");
    }
  })
})
```

For mouseout

```
$('nav').mouseout(function() {
  var navbar = $('.nav-visibility')
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() <= $(document).height() && window.scrollY > 0){
    navbar.css("opacity", "0");
  }
});
```

Comment: @jkr137: Can you try this solution and let me know if it works for you...

Comment: thank's for the fast response. doesn't work either. the whole site is now black :).

Comment: Do you have any link for the site

Comment: great! 1 small problem: the nav appears while reaching the bottom BUT when you hovering the nav and leaving it = the nav is gone = opacity: 0;

Comment: still the same but now it also disappears between top and bottom... and they're clickable even you can't see the nav.

Comment: my fault: i forgot the mouseover... = otherwise still the same... it disappears after hovering

Comment: @jkr137: My mouseout answer seems to work at my end, so is the nav disappearing on both top and bottom

Comment: i've just managed to fix it! thank you so much for your help! and btw i'm a bit proud of myself :') - i just did something and it works (absolutely beginner in coding)

Answer (score 0):

#### Scroll Event Method:

```
 document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if((document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight){
       // Do something!
       // document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute("style", "display: none");
    }
 }, true);
```

#### Example:

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        if((document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight){
          document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = "Reached Bottom";     
           document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute("style", "height: 100px;");
       }
}, true);
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="height: 1800px">Scroll to Bottom</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer for proof. Are you sure your JS file is being called?

Comment: thank's for your response as well! it's so strange... it won't work for some reason. i've tested it with a window alert and it worked. Pawan Jangid solution works right now but has 1 tiny bug.

Comment: When reach bottom try using `document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0");` instead of css opacity. `foo` will be your navigation id attribute.

Comment: That way you don't rely on jQuery and performance wise much better.

Comment: that works, but not with navigation id attribute... the whole site is black

`document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
   if((document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight){
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
   }
}, true);`

Comment: Well, I can't tell you because I don't see your entire code. I think that is due to your CSS. but the `scroll` event method should work if you're writing your styling code correctly.

Comment: it's so strange... unfortunately this site is not online. 

btw that's the styling code
`.nav-visibility {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again guys! The problem is fixed and it works like how I expected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navbar = $('.nav-visibility')
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    //Check for top and bottom
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() || $(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
      navbar.css("opacity", "1");
    } else {
      navbar.css("opacity", "0");
    }
  })
})

$('nav').mouseover(function() {
  $('.nav-visibility').css("opacity", "1");

});

$('nav').mouseout(function() {
  var navbar = $('.nav-visibility')
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() && window.scrollY > 0) {
    navbar.css("opacity", "0");
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() && window.scrollY < 0) {
    navbar.css("opacity", "1");
  }
});
```